# How to install npm packages on StackBlitz?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, stackblitz

I just want to install npm packages for angular on StackBlitz. How can I do that since there is no terminal on StackBlitz?

Comment: Check out their docs. Basically just add the package and stackblitz should prompt you to install it if it's not already. At least, that's how they have the angular template setup: https://stackblitz.com/docs

Comment: @mwilson can you elaborate on what you mean by "add the package"? should I add it to `package.json` or just import it in `app.moudle.ts` or what you mean exactly?

Comment: @JasonWhite oh ok I see

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Under the "Files" tree is a "Dependencies" section.  You can add your dependencies there.  If you just want the latest version you can just use the package name (ex: `ngx-bootstrap`) or you can target a specific version (ex: `ngx-bootstrap@5.3.0`).

[image]

#### Update 9/5/2022 NextJS

It looks like dependencies are not auto installed for NextJS projects.  You do have access to a terminal under the code editor though.  If you set focus to this terminal you can Ctrl+C to stop the dev server.  You then can install you dependencies from this terminal.

`npm install --save <package-name>`

Then just restart the dev server with...

`npx next dev`.

Hopefully this helps for NextJS users.

Comment: And another way is to modify the package.json file and save

Comment: does that automatically add all packages ?

Comment: There is no dependencies panel now.

Comment: @FrankFang It looks like some project types don't have the dependencies panel now.  React and Angular still do.  If there isn't you'll just have to modify the package.json file manually.

Comment: Next JS React stackblitz doesnt have a dependencies and just adding to package.json does not install the module. This seriously affects Stackblitz useability compared to Codesandbox

Comment: @LaurenceFass  I just spun up a NextJS quickly. Didn't fully test this because I don't know much about NextJS, but there is a terminal at the bottom that you have access to.  If you focus this and Ctrl+C you have access to that terminal.  You then can modify the `package.json` and in the terminal do `npm install && npx next dev`.  Again didn't fully test this, just something you can try.  You could also use this terminal to install dependencies with npm, `npm install --save <package-name>`.